# mean of repeated measures...spot the (matlab) error

Tags: repeated-measures, mean

I have a population of 114 subjects.
For each subject I have repeated measurements (1 each day) of the variable assessed (activity level). 
The number of measures varies for each subject (number of assessed days) and the median number of measures for each subject is 4.

Data can be downloaded [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WVZZmRrbUXfk-1OODohog_O5vSej-bmD614rApqFz4Y/edit)

Can I simply take the average of the measures to continue with my statistical analysis of the population, i.e. each subject will be represented by the average measure across the assessed days.
Should I perform a statistical test before doing that? which one?

Could you please suggest the workflow?
**My purpose is to find whether there are differences in the variable measured between group of subjects** (lets say first 57 subjects are groupA and last 57 subjects are group B).

My attempt (results are obtained using MATLAB, but should be interpretable):

- I fit a repeated model of the type 't1-t5 ~ Group' meaning that measurements t1-t5 are the responses and the groups is the predictor variable

  Time = [1 2 3 4 5]' %array contaning the day of assessment

  rm = [fitrm](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrm.html?searchHighlight=fitrm)(table,'t1-t5 ~ Group','WithinDesign',Time) %table is a matlab table contaning the data

the coefficients of the models are

```
                   t1         t2         t3         t4        t5   
                 _______    _______    _______    ______    _______

(Intercept)       425.64     412.64     425.64    414.05     443.64
Group_A          -52.182    -12.636    -23.182     -47.5    -45.455
```

- I check Mauchly's test for sphericity

  tbl = [mauchly](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel.mauchly.html?searchHighlight=mauchly)(rm) % if small use the correction when compute p value in ranova

> tbl =
>
> ```
>    W       ChiStat    DF    pValue 
> _______    _______    __    _______
>
> 0.84303    3.1446     9     0.95828
> ```

p value is > than 0.05 so I do not have to correct the repeated ANOVA

- I run repeated ANOVA

  ranovatbl = [ranova](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel.ranova.html?searchHighlight=ranova)(rm)

> ranovatbl =
>
> ```
>                       SumSq       DF    MeanSq       F       pValue     pValueGG    pValueHF    pValueLB
>                     __________    __    ______    _______    _______    ________    ________    ________
>
> (Intercept):Time         13611     4    3402.6    0.98232    0.42203    0.41863     0.42203     0.33347 
> Group:Time               26256     4    6564.1      1.895    0.11938    0.12457     0.11938     0.18386 
> Error(Time)         2.7711e+05    80    3463.9
> ```

It tells me that there are no effect of days in the activity level, and there are no differences between groups.

- I compute the marginal means

  M = [margmean](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel.margmean.html?searchHighlight=margmean)(rm,{'Group'})

> ```
>  Group      Mean     StdErr    Lower     Upper 
> _______    ______    ______    ______    ______
>
> A          388.13    18.68     349.16    427.09
> B          460.51    18.68     421.54    499.47
> ```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the mean for each day, because these means are computed with a different number of terms. Probably you should look at mixed effect models, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166434/how-to-account-for-participants-in-a-study-design/166449#166449

Comment: Thanks. Is repeated ANOVA OK? Should I test any assumption before using it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Well I don't know mathlab and without data it is not easy to tell how to proceed in detail but it sounds as if you want to estimate something like $y=\beta_1 + \beta_2 G + \epsilon$ where $y$ is the number of steps, $G$ the group.  The problem you have is that your var-covar matrix of $\epsilon$ is not diagonal because of the repeated measures, so you have to use Generalised Least Squares (GLS) to estimate it, using several var-covar patterns (unstructured, compound symmetry, ...) and decide which one fits best (with likelihood ratio test). (see the reference in the answer on the patients)

Comment: Hi,
according to the ANOVA for repeated measurements (see question) I think that I can say that there is not significant effect of the repeated measurements (time) on the measured variables and on the groups...maybe then I can take the mean right?

Comment: Sorry but without data it is hard to tell whether this is 'right' or 'wrong' or whether one 'can do' this, I don't know which assumptions have been made (e.g. for the var-covar structure) but as far as I am concerned you are free to 'take' whatever you want :-)

Comment: @fcoppens :) Please have a look at my edited question...I also uploaded the data...if you can take the time to help me I would really appreciate it

Comment: This would really depends on which questions you want to answer (e.g. is there any interest in whether things change over time or is the interest only in the average?). What are your questions that you want to answer? Note also that you probably want to deal with missing data based on the uncollapsed dataset, because in many real datasets variability increases over time.

Comment: Hi, my question is: Is the activity level different between group A and group B considering the assessed days?

Comment: On the link below it is said that ANOVA in mathlab uses compound symmetry, my computations in R (likelihood ratio test) that there is no significant difference with an unstuctured covariancematrix.  Does mathlab give you the means of the two groups ? http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/compound-symmetry-assumption-and-epsilon-corrections.html

Comment: I added the marginal means in my question...thanks for taking the time of having a look

Comment: I am struggling because if I take the mean for each patient, then groupA is statistically different from groupB. If I use repeated ANOVA not anymore..

Comment: I don't know how you found these values for the means (marginal means) but the way I did it (gls function in R, using compound symmetry var-covar matrix) I find that your two groups are different (p-value 0.036) and with an unstructure var-covar matrix the p-value is 0.066) but the likelihood ratio test suggests that I should take compound symmetry.

Comment: What are the mean values that you found? I will post my code...

Comment: I have 405.5342 for A and 405.5342+26.0198 for B

Comment: wow...that's very different from my result...

Comment: I edited my question providing all the code that I used with the references...we could start a chat to discuss about it if you have time..

Answer (score 1):

I imported your dataset, converted it to long form, and ran a mixed model in R. I used the packages lme4 and lmerTest:

```
M1 <- lmer(outcome ~ group + time + (1|ID), data=cv.long)
```

As you can see, I included time as a linear independent variable and ID (person ID) as a random constant. This gives an estimate of 25.266 for belonging to group B, and std. error 12.328. P = 0.0427, so this model supports a slight difference between the groups.

I loaded the data to SPSS, converted the variables that had NaN's to numeric variables, and saved the data to a .sav file. I also changed group A to 1 and group B to 2. I then applied the following code in R:

```
library(foreign)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
cv.data <- read.spss("/Users/jonasberge/Dropbox/R/crossvalidated_data.sav",  to.data.frame = T)
cv.long <- reshape(cv.data, 
    varying = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"), 
    v.names = "outcome",
    timevar = "time", 
    times = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
    direction = "long")
M1 <- lmer(outcome ~ Group + time + (1|id), data=cv.long)
summary(M1)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['lmerMod']
Formula: outcome ~ Group + time + (1 | id)
   Data: cv.long

REML criterion at convergence: 5376.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3032 -0.5652  0.0447  0.5502  4.6394 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 3213     56.69   
 Residual             4482     66.95   
Number of obs: 466, groups:  ID, 114

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  401.707     11.078 252.600  36.263   <2e-16 ***
Group2        25.266     12.328 112.200   2.049   0.0427 *  
time           1.421      2.610 361.300   0.545   0.5864    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) group2
Group2 -0.572       
time   -0.613  0.019
```

You can download the dataset here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/42y6sgtznl1wfju/crossvalidated_data.sav?dl=0

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! thanks! what I do in matlab is fitting a repeated measures model, where the measurements t1-t5 are the responses and the groups is the predictor variable. Could you have a look at http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel.margmean.html?searchHighlight=margmean to see in what we differ?

Comment: Hi, very interested in checking your lmer call, but I can't find the data. Can you help? The hyperlink in OP leads me to some mathlab info. Ty

Comment: data is back...sorry

Comment: I updated the post and included a link so that you can download the data in long form. I have no experience in using matlab so I can't help you there, I'm sorry.

Comment: [R code to convert your data to long form](https://github.com/RInterested/HOW_TO/blob/master/WIDE%20to%20LONG%20DATA%20FRAME)

Comment: @JonasBerge How did you convert NaN to numbers?

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile, I learned to use reshape(). Perhaps tidyr() is better? And I didn't know about gsheet, cool!

Comment: @Antoni: I loaded the data in SPSS first and changed the variable type from string to numeric. This automatically changes all non-numbers to missing data while keeping the numbers.

Comment: @JonasBerge There was a careless mistake on my code with tidyr(), which is now fixed. So if you go to the link I provided above, and don't mind  just copying and running the whole thing, I'd like to know if you find any differences with your work. For instance, I get intersects for every time. I just haven't been able to see your data after SPSS.

Comment: @Antoni: I'm not sure what you mean by intersects? I imported your code and your model M1 gives slightly different results because the time variable is a factor. If I run a modified model with as.numeric(time) instead of time, the output is identical to the code I provided in my answer above! : M1 <- lmer(outcome ~ group + as.numeric(time) + (1|ID), data=data_long). Of course, using time as a numeric variable assumes that the intervals between time points are equal and the relationship linear, which may not be the case.

Comment: @JonasBerge Cool! Thanks for following through... I meant "intercepts".