# Wikipedia says that "The random effects model is a special case of the fixed effects model". Why?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I understand that the assumption made in a fixed effects model is that there is a basic understanding of the included parameters, e.g. there is a proven theory or previous experiments have shown non-random effects of the parameters.

In a random effects model, however, a parameter is treated as a random variable. Effects are completely random samples form a larger population.

This leads to my question: Why, then, is the random effects model--at least according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model) --considered a special case of the fixed effects model?

> The random effects model is a special case of the fixed effects model.

To me, it more seems as if they are complete opposites.

Comment: I think the sentence "The random effects model is a special case of the fixed effects model" is wrong. If at all, it should be the other way round: fixed effect can be seen as a random effect with zero variance.

Comment: But is it always the case that fixed effects have zero variance? Also according to Wikipedia, a fixed effect can has non-random variability. This isn't the same as zero variance...

Comment: Two advices: (1) don't trust Wikipedia in this topic. (2) Look at the math, not at verbal descriptions. Then you will see what the difference really is.

Comment: There are several good discussions of FE, RE, their relationship and the use(s) of these terms in different fields on this site. See, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238214/how-exactly-does-a-random-effects-model-in-econometrics-relate-to-mixed-models, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188349/use-of-fixed-effects-and-random-effects, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode

Comment: I think you mean: Random Effect Model is a special case of the Random Parameter Model.